# Hidden Button Click in HTML through VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, attributes

```
<tr>
    **<td>**JB - Al Qouz**</td>**
    **<td>**
        <strong>0</strong>
        <input type="hidden" name="ingredient[inventories_attributes][][id]" id="ingredient_inventories_attributes__id" value="5564069">
      <small><span class="buyUnitValueText ">pc</span></small>
      <small><b><span id="totalStockValue_1" class="hide paddingLeft15 updateTotalStockValue"></span></b></small>
    **</td>**
    **<td>**
      <div class="align-left">
        <input type="text" name="ingredient[inventories_attributes][][reorder_level]" id="ingredient_inventories_attributes__reorder_level" value="0" class="span5 menuItemInventory reOrderValue">
        <small><span class="buyUnitValueText span7 labelText pull-right align-left">pc</span>
        </small>
      </div>
    **</td>**
    <td class="align-left">
      <input type="hidden" name="ingredient[inventories_attributes][][track_inventory]" id="track_inventory_9971" **value="true"**>
      **<div class="vCheckBox trackInventoryCheckbox active" id="9971"></div>**
```

I need to change 2 things (See Bold) if `"id=9971"` through vba.

1. Set class `vCheckBox trackInventoryCheckbox active` to class `vCheckBox trackInventoryCheckbox`
2. Set `value="true"` to `value="false"`

Reason being, I'm not able to click the button through VBA and the code change in html that occurs when I click manually are the 1. & 2. mentioned above.

Please advise, below is my code where I tried to get tag value through `tr` but couldn't, second part was where I could change the values.

```
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate (EditIngredientURL)
    
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        While .document.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend
    End With
    
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
    Set tr = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    For Each trObj In tr
        Set td = trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each tdObj In td
            If InStr(tdObj.innerText, "JB - Al Qouz") Then
                Debug.Print tdObj.innerText
    
                Set CheckBox = tdObj.getElementsByTagName("class")
                For Each idnumber In CheckBox
                    Debug.Print idnumber.innerText
                    Exit For
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Replied with the code I tried to used to get the value of the class in td first so I could change it, issue is - first: I'm unable to get the value of attribute "value" in <input. Second, I'm unsure how'd I parse <div to read the ID and then change the class attached to it.

Comment: To me it is unclear wether you know this id number `id=9971` or if it is unknown?

Comment: The "id=9971" is related to "JB - Al Qouz" and is known to me since the start of the code, I can use it as a reference base to change 1. & 2. there.

Comment: Try `HTMLdoc.getElementById("track_inventory_9971").value = "false"` and `HTMLdoc.getElementById("9971").className = "vCheckBox trackInventoryCheckbox"`

Comment: That worked out perfect! Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is known and you have it in a variable `idNo` you can use it to locate the elements:

```
idNo = "9971"

HTMLdoc.getElementById("track_inventory_" & idNo).value = "false"

HTMLdoc.getElementById(idNo).className = "vCheckBox trackInventoryCheckbox"
```